# Can diskshadow be installed in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, vss, backup

After finding out about diskshadow, I wanted to install it the systems I backup, there aren't issues with windows 2008 server, but I can't find the program in windows 8 (it's a pro version)
On microsoft's site it specifies windows 8 as a target [technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx) with a quote like

> Applies To: Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012

NOTE: I discovered diskshadow via [this](https://superuser.com/questions/394296/is-there-a-tool-to-copy-a-folder-using-shadow-copy?answertab=votes#tab-top), that was mostly what I was trying to accomplish.

How can I install it?

Comment: **DiskShadow.exe** is only part of the Server Versions. Looks like a typo on the MS page

Comment: I dropped a comment in the site, requesting for clarification, could you point me to the place you got your information? Thanks

Comment: I simply checked my system32 folder in Win8 and can't find the exe. So I opened a WIM of Server 2012 and here I see the tool.

Comment: Oh, that's what I did too, but I thought that i might be installable as a part of an sdk such as the VSS

Comment: I haven't found anything where you can download it. Try to copy it from a 2012 Install and see what happens.